# General Solution for both online and on-premise?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I developed a general solution for CRM 2011, which contains plug-ins , javascripts and entities etc... But the problem I am facing is that while importing this solution into any online instances, I am getting an error "plug-in must be registered by sandbox". I want to use this solution for both on-premise and online. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your code doesn't violate any of the restrictions placed upon it with Sandbox (Isolation) mode (i.e. accessing the registry, the file system, threading, third party assemblies and similar) then your resolution may be as simple as changing the Isolation Mode of your plug-ins to "Sandbox" before re-exporting your solution and trying to import it again Online.

Try that first. If it fails and you don't understand why, post some code here :)

Answer (score 4):

In Dynamics CRM Online - plugins must be registered in Sandbox mode.  You'll need to design it as such from the beginning if you want it to work in both online and on premise environments.

[Plug-in Isolation, Trusts, and Statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx)